RSA key generation infinite processing
import 'package:rsa_encrypt/rsa_encrypt.dart';
import 'package:pointycastle/api.dart' as crypto;

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding
      .ensureInitialized(); // Ensures Flutter bindings are initialized
//Future to hold our KeyPair
  Future<crypto.AsymmetricKeyPair> futureKeyPair = getKeyPair();
//to store the KeyPair once we get data from our future
  crypto.AsymmetricKeyPair keyPair = await futureKeyPair;

  print(keyPair);
}

Future<crypto.AsymmetricKeyPair<crypto.PublicKey, crypto.PrivateKey>>
    getKeyPair() {
  var helper = RsaKeyHelper();
  return helper.computeRSAKeyPair(helper.getSecureRandom());
}

The problem is I am trying to generate rsa key pair, but I get info infinite computation problem.
I have tried using pointycastle github repo code as well
https://github.com/PointyCastle/pointycastle/blob/master/tutorials/rsa.md

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding
      .ensureInitialized(); // Ensures Flutter bindings are initialized
// //Future to hold our KeyPair
//   Future<crypto.AsymmetricKeyPair> futureKeyPair = getKeyPair();
// //to store the KeyPair once we get data from our future
//   crypto.AsymmetricKeyPair keyPair = await futureKeyPair;


final pair = generateRSAkeyPair(exampleSecureRandom());
final public = pair.publicKey;
final private = pair.privateKey;

  print(private.toString());
  print("keys generated");
}

AsymmetricKeyPair<RSAPublicKey, RSAPrivateKey> generateRSAkeyPair(
    SecureRandom secureRandom,
    {int bitLength = 2048}) {
  // Create an RSA key generator and initialize it

  final keyGen = RSAKeyGenerator()
      ..init(ParametersWithRandom(
          RSAKeyGeneratorParameters(BigInt.parse('65537'), bitLength, 64),
          secureRandom));

  // Use the generator

  final pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();

  // Cast the generated key pair into the RSA key types

  final myPublic = pair.publicKey as RSAPublicKey;
  final myPrivate = pair.privateKey as RSAPrivateKey;

  return AsymmetricKeyPair<RSAPublicKey, RSAPrivateKey>(myPublic, myPrivate);
}

SecureRandom exampleSecureRandom() {
  final secureRandom = FortunaRandom();

  final seedSource = Random.secure();
  final seeds = <int>[];
  for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    seeds.add(seedSource.nextInt(255));
  }
  secureRandom.seed(KeyParameter(Uint8List.fromList(seeds)));

  return secureRandom;
}


in this example my code execution never reach the print statements it keeps on executing forever.

What doesn't work with the pointycastle example code? It works fine for me.

How are you trying to run this code? Like when I run it as flutter project it's working. (with your code) The app is launched with blank screen and the print statement is also working. "Instance of 'AsymmetricKeyPair<PublicKey, PrivateKey>'". I am able to run this on a button click also. But when I try to run it in flutter web, then the UI is freezing for almost 40 seconds then print the value otherwise it's working in real android device.

Yes its working fine on phone but not on browser for some reason. Thanks everyone for help.
